# How to merge data sets when there are multiple of the "keys"

Tags: r, merge, tidyverse, data-manipulation

I'm trying to merge two data sets in `R`. For reference the key is an employee `ID number`. In the first data set, `A`, the key is unique and each variable corresponds to the `ID number`. In the next dataset we have the same `ID number`, however the data refers to the number of times someone has been promoted. Thus the `ID number` repeats multiple times for each separate move. I want to merge the two so that I only have the one `ID number`, with the information about each move.

I'm new to this and I've already tried the `join` functions in the `tidy verse` package and I'm trying to find a way to join when the key is repeated.

```
Example of the datasets
[A]
ID     "Status"
1.     Y
2.     N
3.     Y
4.     N
5.     Y

[B]

ID    "Movement"
1      AB
1      BC
2.     AB
3.     AA
3.     AB
3.     BC
4.     AA
5.     AB
5.     BA
```

I want it to look like this in the end

```
ID    "STATUS".  "Movement 1" "Movement 2" Movement 3" .....
1         Y           AB          BC          NA
2         N           AB          NA          NA
3         Y           AA          AB          BC
4         N           AA          NA          NA
5         Y           AB          BA          NA
```

Thanks for your support!

Answer (score 0):

An option would be to join the two datasets by 'ID' and then `spread` it to 'wide' format after creating a sequence column grouped by 'ID'

```
library(tidyverse)
left_join(df2, df1) %>%
   group_by(ID) %>% 
   mutate(col = str_c("Movement", row_number())) %>% 
   spread(col, Movement)
# A tibble: 5 x 5
# Groups:   ID [5]
#     ID Status Movement1 Movement2 Movement3
#  <dbl> <chr>  <chr>     <chr>     <chr>    
#1     1 Y      AB        BC        <NA>     
#2     2 N      AB        <NA>      <NA>     
#3     3 Y      AA        AB        BC       
#4     4 N      AA        <NA>      <NA>     
#5     5 Y      AB        BA        <NA>
```

#### data

```
df <- structure(list(ID = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5), Status = c("Y", "N", "Y", 
"N", "Y")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -5L))

df2 <- structure(list(ID = c(1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 5, 5), Movement = c("AB", 
"BC", "AB", "AA", "AB", "BC", "AA", "AB", "BA")), 
  class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-9L))
```